# String Builder Enum checking

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, enums

I  have collection table in database which have fields:

```
published,name,descrption and collection_type.
```

And this `collection_type` can be three different String  values :`Collection,Trend,Occasion`.

Showing whole elements with this working.

```
public List<Collection> list() {
   QueryParams queryParams = new QueryParams();
   queryParams.setWhere("published = true");
   return list(queryParams);
}
```

But showing specific elements for example Occasions failed. How to fix the code to show the elements?

```
public List<Collection> occasions() {
    QueryParams queryParams = new QueryParams();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("published = true ");
    sb.append("AND collection_type = '");
    sb.append("CollectionType.OCCASION.getName()'");
    queryParams.setWhere(sb.toString());       
    return list(queryParams);
}        

public enum CollectionType {           
    COLLECTION("COLLECTION"), TREND("TREND"), OCCASION("OCCASION");          
    private String name;          
    private CollectionType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }         
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }           
}
```

Comment: I can't answer your question as I'm not sure what you are doing, but I do know that `Enum` already has a method `name`, that does exactly what your `getName` method does. All you need is `public enum CollectionType { COLLECTION, TREND, OCCASION }`

Comment: When you say `sb.append("CollectionType.OCCASION.getName()'");`, do you mean `sb.append(CollectionType.OCCASION.getName()); sb.append("'")` ? or `sb.append("OCCASION'");`

Comment: i have list of elements in database. This  table in db contains collection_type(string),name,description etc. I want to display elements where collection_type for example =  "OCCASION";

Comment: "How to fix errors" Please state what the errors are.

Comment: there is not errors. Sorry i am a little bit tired today ... I meaned that  query not working. There is not output at site with this method. List<Collection> occasions()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, the problem is, that you don't set a ENUM's name, but a "CollectionType.OCCASION.getName()'" string. Try to change your code to:

```
public List<Collection> occasions() {
    QueryParams queryParams = new QueryParams();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("published = true ");
    sb.append("AND collection_type = '");
    sb.append(CollectionType.OCCASION.getName());
    sb.append("'");
    queryParams.setWhere(sb.toString());

    return list(queryParams);
}
```